# Predefined symbol to select between Lazarus and Delphi

Tags: delphi, freepascal, lazarus, conditional-compilation

I am looking for a predefined symbol to write a code like that:

```
{$IFDEF LAZARUS}
// code compiles by fpc/lazarus
{$ELSE}
// code compiles by delphi
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `FPC`

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
```

Comment: `FPC` is defined by the compiler rather than the IDE. So it will be correct for all IDEs that use FPC as their compiler.

Comment: Yes I don't think there's a directive to detect the IDE at all. After all, the IDE is just an enriched Notepad to type your code in.

Comment: IDE itself could possibly define a conditional symbol, and store it in compiler options.

Comment: What does it matter which IDE is invoking the compiler?

Comment: Maybe he thinks IDE = widgets library, hence Lazarus = LCL.

Comment: I also think the code should check for **both FPC and Delphi**. There is GNU Pascal, there is Virtual Pascal, OpenSibil, MIDlet Pascal and who knows what else, even Oxygene is compatible to some point.
I am certain that both FPC and DELPHI should be checked.
Maybe they should be checked once in the header, and if none defined then abort compilation due to non-supported compiler. But at lease once Delphi presence should be ensured

Comment: I am porting a unit test project to Lazarus and need ex to use different unit names in `uses` clause. DUnit implementation is specific to IDE.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with built-in Lazarus GUI testrunner

Comment: @Arioch: starting in XE2 (or maybe XE, I forget which), the Delphi compiler started defining the `DCC` conditional for itself. Prior to that, there was no defining conditional to identify the Delphi compiler, except indirectly via the version-specific `VERxxx` conditionals.

Comment: @GolezTrol: not so simple as in Delphi you may have some code related to the IDE itself, ie: when you use ToolsAPI.

Comment: @az01 That is still compiled using the Delphi compiler (for the Delphi IDE) or by FreePascal if you compile (for) Lazarus.

Comment: Maybe in combination with a define for designtime parts of components

Answer (score 1):

For GUI applications afaik the "**LCL**" symbol is defined inside Lazarus projects.  In this case it probably won't matter.

In general, for bigger codebases, I would avoid having too much ifdef FPC/LCL and ifdef  in your sourcecode though. It makes adding an exception or other version harder.

Use a system like JCL and Zeos(7) are using, where you give most differences an own name (like "USE_FPCUNIT" or "USE_DUNIT") and link these to versions in a central includefile.

For a short treatise on the subject see http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/porting.pdf (chapter 2)

P.s. I would consider Pocketstudio, TP,GPC,VP and WDSybil (and whatever I forgot) dead for most practical purposes and the bytecode variants Canterbury Pascal/Component Pascal/Oxygene/Prism/Delphi.NET incompatible (most are more Oberon than Pascal anyway). That pretty much leaves Delphi, Kylix and FPC to worry about.